# The 'poster' attribute does not have a file associated with it"

Tags: python, html, django

The following error occurs

> The 'poster' attribute does not have a file associated with it

I don't quite understand what it may be related to and how to fix it
I tried to change the url value, but nothing worked.

html

```html
<div class="container" style="grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 300px);">
 for serial in serials %}
         <div class="item">
             <img src="{{ serial.poster.url }}" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                 <p>
                     <a href="{% url 'detail_serial' serial.url %}">{{ serial.title }}</a>
                </p>
         </div>
 endfor %}
</div>
```

views.py

```
class SerialDetailView(View):
def get(self, request):
serials = Serials.objects.all()
genres = Genre.objects.all()
return render(request, "serials/single_serial.html", {"serials": serials, "genres": genres})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('register/', views.Register.as_view(), name='register'),
path('reg/', views.Reg.as_view(), name='reg'),
path("serials_list/", views.SerialsView.as_view(), name='serials_list'),
path("add/", views.AddView.as_view(), name='add'),
path("single_serial/", views.SerialDetailView.as_view(), name='single_serial'),
path("<slug:slug>/", views.SingleSerial.as_view(), name='detail_serial'),
path("actor/<int:id>/", views.ActorView.as_view(), name='actor_detail'),
]
```

My models

```
class Serials(models.Model):
title = models.CharField('Name',max_length=100)
description = models.CharField('Description', max_length= 200)
poster = models.ImageField('Poster', upload_to='serials/')
date = models.DateField('Date')
country = models.CharField('Страна',max_length=100)
actors = models.ManyToManyField(Actor, verbose_name='actors', related_name='actor')  
genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, verbose_name='genres')  
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name='category', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)   
url = models.SlugField(unique=False)
link = models.URLField(max_length=200, blank=True)
```

Comment: Please add your `Serials` model, is the `Serials.poster` field nullable?

Comment: Post the *full* traceback...

Comment: @IainShelvington

add model in comments

Comment: I have fixed a number of the formatting issues in your question, and moved the models that you posted as an answer (as it will likely be deleted soon, as it is in the review queue) but you should still [edit] your answer to fix the indentation (editors usually leave indentation issues for Python problems for the OP to fix as it might hide a problem with your implementation). As stated above, you should also add the full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to display the image of one of the serials while you did not choose an image for it.
First, choose an image for all serials poster or use the following code:

```
<div class="container" style="grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 
            300px);">
            for serial in serials %}
                    <div class="item">
                    {% if serial.poster %}
                        <img src="{{ serial.poster.url }}" class="img-fluid" 
                        alt="">
                    {% endif %}
                            <p>
                                <a href="{% url 'detail_serial' serial.url %}">{{ serial.title }}</a>
                            </p>
                    </div>
            {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, now its work, but now I have this problem, do you know how it fix?
Reverse for 'detail_serial' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\\Z']